# Improving startup time for java web application in glassfish 3.1

Tags: classpath, glassfish-3

I am trying to reduce the start up time of my web application deployed in glassfish 3.1.1 (build 12) application server. My web application is deployed as a war file containing multiple jar files for every module in the application. The jar files are located in the WEB-INF\lib directory.

On enabling detailed logs for glassfish, I saw that glassfish tries to search the class files in WEB-INF\classes and does not find it. Since there are more than 16K classes there is an error message for every class file.

```
|FINE   |org.apache.naming_.FileDirContext| 88|PWC4451: File cannot be read E:\glassfish3.1.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\mywebapp\WEB-INF\classes\com.xxx.yyy.MyClass.class
```

I added a emtpy jar named all-jars.jar in WEB-INF\lib and it contains a MANIFEST.MF file with a classpath attribute. The Class-Path attribute looks as below.

```
Class-Path: WEB-INF/lib/a.jar WEB-INF/lib/b.jar WEB-INF/lib/c.jar
```

Adding this jar didn't help though.

How can I tell glassfish to not search in WEB-INF/classes directory? Also any other suggestions to reduce the start up time?